# What is the right way to deal with AJAX on Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

On most tutorials out there, people tell you to create a `js.erb` template for every action you want to respond with `javascript`, which leads to having both an `html.erb` and a `js.erb`, for **every** action I want to work with AJAX, like this:

[image]

Is this right? Am I doing something wrong? Because it looks awful to me, there will be at least 20 files in each view folder, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it looks really awful to me too. But if you're responding to every method with javascript you'll have to create `js.erb` templates for each them.

Another approach would be, you'd want to respond with json instead of script. Where all your ajax code will remain in the client side javascript, and you'll be responded back with json data.

For eg. lets get data for an particular area

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/areas/23",
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'get',
  success: function(response){
    //OPTION 1
    //response will have all the data
    //handle the value from the response object in displaying


    //OPTION 2
    //If you set dataType: 'html' you can receive html partial from server and make use of it directly
    $("#show-area").html(response); //response will have content of _show.html.erb
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error); //Print errors if it breaks
  }
});


#Controller
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    #OPTIONS 1
    format.json { render json: @area.as_json } 
    #Or have a json.jbuilder partial if you want to send data selectively, ;) There is no escape from partials/templates

    #OPTION 2
    format.html { render partial: "areas/show" } # will render _show.html.erb

  end
end
```

That being said, I think it finally comes to personal preference. And your preferences will vary upon different scenarios. You can pick any one of those based on the case. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: My application relies heavily on AJAX calls, so I guess I can't really escape this :( The application is quite new, and considering this issue, do you think it's worth it to move the views to something like React, or something more radical like Angular?

Comment: `js.erb` is not bad at all. But yes absolutely. I was going to suggest you that. Use rails for an `api` purpose only which will handle data in `json` format. And using a MV* js framework in the front end will ease things a lot. And since your app is in a very young stage, it'll be easy to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing right. You are using Rails’ AJAX helper and it is a good practice. Some advantages of this comparing to the normal way of using AJAX:

- JS code is shorter and cleaner, we do not need to write some repeated boring code such as $("form#id").on("submit", function(){}). We just need to write the main code to handle the response data.
- Unobtrusive JavaScript: JS code is rendered from server side. It is not shown along with the html.
- I think splitting to js.erb files actually makes the code more manageable. It is personal thought though.

I don't know how complex your project is so I am not sure but maybe you can refine to have less partial files. For example, I noticed that you have both **delete** and **destroy** actions. **Index**, **new** and **edit** views may not need the partial files. It seems that you also handle Json requests. It also makes the view folder bigger.